# Upgrade back to php 5.3 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, php

Running 11.04 and I downgraded down to php5.2 due to some needs. I don't remember how. I'd like to get back up to 5.3 now. I'm trying to use apt-get upgrade but I get the following messages:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2 is installed
 libgssapi-krb5-2 : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2) but 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2 is installed
 libkrb5-3 : Depends: libk5crypto3 (>= 1.9+dfsg~beta1) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2 is installed
             Depends: libkrb5support0 (= 1.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I'm not having any luck finding any leads on how to fix.

Let me know if I should provide more information.

EDIT: adding listing of /etc/apt/preferences.d

```
:/etc/apt/preferences.d$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-10-15 11:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2012-02-07 23:39 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  738 2011-10-15 11:14 php
```

Listing of /etc/apt

```
/etc/apt$ ll
total 76
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 2012-02-07 23:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x 161 root root 12288 2012-02-09 09:36 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-11-29 10:47 apt.conf.d/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-10-15 11:14 preferences.d/
-rw-------   1 root root     0 2011-04-25 18:52 secring.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3277 2012-01-02 20:14 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2012-01-03 09:44 sources.list.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3277 2012-01-02 20:14 sources.list.save
-rw-------   1 root root  1200 2012-01-02 20:05 trustdb.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 13937 2012-01-02 20:05 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 13937 2012-01-02 20:05 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-04-07 07:13 trusted.gpg.d/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `this may be caused by held packages`

Yep, that's probably it. `aptitude` is a very handy interactive cli tool for installing packages and also for investigating when odd things happen.

Try it out, it'll likely tell you what's wrong (or what breaks when you try and upgrade php).

Comment: Thanks. I do not have aptitude installed and when I try to do so, I get an error that the package system is broken and nothing else can be installed without that being fixed.

I don't know if downloading the .deb and installing that way is a workaround. Thoughts?

Comment: You should probably post the contents of `/etc/apt/preferences` and look for any non-standardness in `/etc/apt/`.

Comment: Update - I have discovered I do have aptitude. It wasn't showing as installed using Software Manager - that's what I get for trusting a GUI. Let me go play with that now.

Comment: I just reinstalled Ubuntu 11.04 to deal with it. Thanks for the help.